# Identifier 'React' has already been declared when building npm package with nx:rollup

Tags: reactjs, rollupjs, nrwl-nx

EDIT: opened an issue ( https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/17769 ) in the nx repo, asking for nx team's help, as well.

I'm trying to build an NPM package using latest nx rollup executor, but halfway building the package, I'm getting the following error and the build fails.

```js
Bundling components...
       Error during bundle: Error: unknown: Identifier 'React' has already been declared. (48:12)
       
         46 |   return target;
         47 | }
       > 48 | import * as React from "react";
            |             ^
         49 | import { forwardRef } from "react";
         50 | var SvgByAsgardeoLabel = function SvgByAsgardeoLabel(_ref, ref) {
         51 |   var title = _ref.title,
       Error during bundle: Error: unknown: Identifier 'React' has already been declared. (48:12)
       
         46 |   return target;
         47 | }
       > 48 | import * as React from "react";
            |             ^
         49 | import { forwardRef } from "react";
         50 | var SvgCodeIcon = function SvgCodeIcon(_ref, ref) {
         51 |   var title = _ref.title,
       Bundle failed: components
       
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

 >  NX   Ran target build for 12 projects (1m)
 
    ✔    8/9 succeeded [0 read from cache]
 
    ✖    1/9 targets failed, including the following:
         - nx run components:build
 
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Following is my rollup.config.cjs.

```js
const nrwlConfig = require("@nx/react/plugins/bundle-rollup");
const url = require("@rollup/plugin-url");
const svgr = require("@svgr/rollup");

module.exports = (config) => {
    const nxConfig = nrwlConfig(config);

    return {
        ...nxConfig,
        plugins: [ ...nxConfig.plugins, 
            url(), 
            svgr({native: true}) ]
    };
};
```

rollup plugin config in `project.json` is as follows.

```js
"build": {
            "executor": "@nx/rollup:rollup",
            "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
            "options": {
                "outputPath": "modules/react-components/dist",
                "tsConfig": "modules/react-components/tsconfig.lib.json",
                "project": "modules/react-components/package.json",
                "entryFile": "modules/react-components/src/index.ts",
                "external": ["react/jsx-runtime"],
                "format": ["esm", "cjs"],
                "rollupConfig": "modules/react-components/rollup.config.cjs",
                "compiler": "babel",
                "assets": [
                    {
                        "glob": "modules/react-components/src/assets",
                        "input": ".",
                        "output": "."
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

The following are the versions of the packages installed.

```
  "@nx/rollup": "16.3.2",
  "@nx/react": "16.3.2",
  "@rollup/plugin-url": "^8.0.1",
  "@svgr/rollup": "^8.0.1",
  "@svgr/webpack": "^8.0.1",
```

Does anyone has an idea what I'm missing here? all help are highly appreciated. TIA!

Comment: I opened an issue for this in nx repo as well https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/17769. According to its comments, the problem seems to be with the @svgr/rollup plugin

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you imported React two times in your code. Check the lines where you imported everything.

Comment: It's not. This happens only after I migrated my nx monorepo from nx 14 to nx 16. So this should be an error related to build config.